# Power Apps Date function connected to Excel

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I am building an app (Power Apps) that has a connection to Excel. In Excel I changed the format as date format. But anyway after I save data in Excel it always shows one day back. And also I cannot show hour and minute correctly.

I would be grateful for a little help.

I can not show hour correctly. The code is: `Hour(Now())`

[image]

It always shows one day back:

[image]